# How do I perform a check on each value of a particular column in jQuery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jquery datatable plugin for tables. I want to perform a check on each value in a column of my choice. How can I do that?

I have tried this but it performs the check on all the values present in the datatable. Is there a way to do this for values in a particular column and not the entire datatable values?

Here's the HTML

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Lots</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here's the Javascript

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bInfo" : false,
  "columns": [
      {"data": "id"},
      {"data": "currency"},
      {"data": "lots"}
  ]
});
table.cells().every( function () {
    if ( this.data() > 5000 ) {
        $(this.node()).addClass( 'warning' );
    }
} );
```

I want all values in the lots column that are greater than 5000 to have class 'warning'.

Comment: Got it to work using this  ----------


table.column(0).cells( function ( idx, data, node ) {
        return data > 5000 ?
            true : false;
}).nodes().to$().addClass( 'warning' );

Comment: You've taken the long way. Option `columns.createdCell` is a natural and much simpler way to achieve that right upon table rendering.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks mate, that was much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use column().nodes(), as described here in the docs:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().nodes()

```
table.column(1).nodes().each( function () {
    if ( this.data() > 5000 ) {
        $(this.node()).addClass( 'warning' );
    }
} );
```